# Compute a series of matrix multiplications and matrix norms quickly in Python

Tags: linear-algebra, numpy

I need to compute a series of matrix multiplications involving 3x3 matrices and a series of matrix norms also involving 3x3 matrices and I wonder how I can set these computations up with numpy such that they are computed quickly (preferably below 10ms).

I am given matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ and I need to compute the following:

$$ \tilde{R}_i=AC_iB $$

$$ o_i=||\tilde{R}\tilde{R}^{T}-I_3||_F $$

Where $\mathbb{C}_i \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}, i\in[1,...,N]$ are matrices that are known beforehand and do not change.

My current approach looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import time

#some constants
N=2**14
C=np.random.rand(3,3,N)+1j*np.random.rand(3,3,N)

#function that does computations
def compute_o(A,B):
    global C
    #perform the computations
    ####################################
    T=np.einsum("ij,jkl",A,C)
    R=np.einsum("lkn,kj",T,B)
    ####################################

#generate random inputs
A=np.random.rand(3,3)+1j*np.random.rand(3,3)
B=np.random.rand(3,3)+1j*np.random.rand(3,3)

#perform computations and estimate time
tic=time.time()
compute_o(A,B)
toc=time.time()
print("Time ellapsed: %fms"%(1e3*(toc-tic)))
```

Basically, I did the initial batch of matrix multiplications using `einsum` which on my computer takes around 2ms. However, I don't quite understand how I can compute the second step without using some sort of loops.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `einsum` with explicit output indices, running over dimension `n` without summing.

```
T = np.einsum("ij,jkn", A, C)
R = np.einsum("ijn,jk", T, B)
S = np.einsum("ijn,kjn->ikn", R, R) - np.eye(3).reshape((3,3,1))
o = np.linalg.norm(S, ord="fro", axis=(0,1))
```

Comment: You could also use `S=np.matmul(R,R,axes=[(0,1),(1,0),(0,1)]) - np.eye(3).reshape((3,3,1))` instead of the `einsum`, but surprisingly this turned out to perform slightly worse for me. No idea why, though I suspect somewhere there's a different loop order which isn't as cache friendly since the results do differ at floating point precision.